# oracle 11g express edition installation failed in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: database

i try to install oracle express edition to Ubuntu 16.04  but
package **alien** is not installing i tried everything but nothing worked it continuously giving this error..

**The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 alien : Depends: debhelper (>= 7) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.**

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOP2F.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install with aptitude:

```
sudo aptitude install alien
```

if you dont have installed aptitude than do:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Comment: tried it too but its not working either it gives the same error.